# iPhone - Printing without any external software, any ideas?

Tags: iphone, printing

Many apps already in App Store has ability to print from iphone without installing any software on computer. Like for example Air-Sharing.

Do anyone have any idea how they're doing it, how they're able to detect from iphone all printers shared in the network and print with them directly from iphone ??

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

thanks
Damian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Air Sharing probably prints through a locally-networked Mac that acts as a [print server](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/8667.html).

Comment: Could you give some more technical suggesions how to achieve this ?

Comment: The Mac opens up LPR ports for its printer sharing. Maybe you would port CUPS over to the iPhone: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Unix_Printing_System Perhaps Air Sharing already uses CUPS or LPR.